# Kudan sample app not launching

Tags: android-studio, kudan, android-augmented-reality

I have problem with launching Kudan sample app on my phone. I am using Kudan in Android Studio.
I created project as was described on website, checked is matches bundeID in my app and on the website(I know key wont be working if they are not the same), Studio doesnt show any errors or warning during compilation, but I cant still launch it on my phone.
Anyone any ideas what might cause it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Generally it could be the issue of mismatched key. In my experience, if the key is not matching then Kudan won't launch and it won't be issue on your side. Could you share your full log for more information?

Comment: add your key and packagename so i can help.